# Zebra striping with CSS selectors

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I've got the following code snippet:

```
<div class="data">
    <h2>Some Title</h2>
    <div id="aPanel75" class="aPanel">
        <span>
            <div class="nameValueHelp field">
                <span class="name">Field Label 1</span>
                <span class="value"><span>Value 1</span></span>
                <span class="help">...</span>
            </div>
        </span>
        <span>
            <div class="nameValueHelp field">
                <span class="name">Field Label 2</span>
                <span class="value"><span>Value 2</span></span>
                <span class="help">...</span>
            </div>
        </span>
        <span>
            <div class="nameValueHelp field">
                <span class="name">Field Label 3</span>
                <span class="value"><span>Value 3</span></span>
                <span class="help">...</span>
            </div>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

that gets zebra striped with a bit of jQuery and CSS:

```
$('.data .field').filter(':even').addClass('odd');
```

and

```
.data .odd {
    background-color: #EDF0F5;
}
```

I'd like to get rid of the jQuery that adds the 'odd' class and just use CSS. I've tried various combinations of the CSS nth-child selector (also nth-of-type). But nothing seems to work, I get all grey and no white.

I think those superfluous span tags around the div.field are the issue, but unfortunately I can't easily change the underlying HTML structure or change any tag classes.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: What you want to do with this. Can you please explain more

Comment: do you wan't same effect without using jQuery and edit the html only

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/tYJ5r/

Comment: Thanks @UmeshA, I want to apply candy striping to the div.field elements without using jQuery, I cannot change the HTML in any way and so I can only use CSS. Unfortunately your suggestion on jsfiddle requires me to change the source HTML which I cannot do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `.field:nth-child(odd)` or `.field:nth-of-type(odd)` as every `.field` is the first and only child `div` of its parent `span`. That might have been where you were getting stuck.

Since each `.field` is embedded in its own parent `span`, and each `span` is a child of your panel `div`, you can use this:

```
.data > .aPanel > span:nth-child(odd) > .field
```

Although I should say that, as much as you can't change the markup, it's still rather unusual for `div`s to be embedded within `span`s... even if browsers will happily construct the DOM accordingly, just remember that it's not wise to rely on such behavior all the time.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. In my defence the HTML comes from Wicket code that someone else abstracted and extended to within an inch of it's life...